# Find all packages in "my" project

Tags: java, project, package

I know already how to get all the packages available, however I'm trying to only get the packages that I made in my own java project.

for example I don't want java.util to show up in the list of packages.

I'm using this code to gather the classes:

```
List<String> result = new LinkedList<String>();

Package[] packages = Package.getPackages();

for(Package pack : packages)
{
    result.add(pack.getName());
}
```

And it works very good, now I just want to get rid of all the system packages.

Is there any way to filter the packages so that only the ones I've defined remain?

PS, I'm not worried about efficiency, the purpose of this can be as slow as it needs to be, it will only run once at the beginning of my program.

I have looked at several related questions, but none of them are what I am looking for.

If there is a way to tell if a package name is a system package, that will do the job perfectly.

EDIT!

I am making this as part of an API, and because of that I can't really just compare the package name against a set token to see if it's a package name I'm using, I don't want there to be any editing required, just place the class file in my project and use it, regardless of what package names I choose.

One method I would try, howver it doesn't seem to work, and gives me random errors, is scanning the jar file to check if there is a directory equivelant to the package name. Whenever I scan the jar file however I get the error "Can not access jar file, is it being used by another process?".

Scanning the jar file would definitly work to see if the class existed in my project (jar file) but another limitation is that I have to compile to test it, can't just test it in Eclipse, I edited the code 10 times trying to get the jar file search to work, and each time get access errors because javaw.exe is using the jar file it's not allowing me to read the files inside of it.

Edit2!

Someone suggested that I make a list of all the known system classes and compare it to that list, which would work if different JDKs didn't have some different classes, so I was wondering a new question sort of, is there any way to get all the jar files that are part of the current JRE System Library? Then I could read through those and add all their packages to the filters.

Comment: How do you distinct between system package, 3rd library package and your packages? Do you have a common prefix such as backwards.url.package1 for all your packages, or any other unique schema?

Comment: could you define a list of parameters that you could match against? so that if you match every package you get against it and only if it applies you use it?

Comment: I am making this in a form part of a small API, this way I can just use this class in any project I need it, in this case yes, but in other cases no, I filtered it a decent amount by making sure it didn't start with java. or javax. however I can't filter the org. and com. and net. and etc because I might need to use those eventually.

Comment: Yes, I could, however a lot of the packages I'm trying to filter are com. org. and net. packages, not just java. and javax. packages, filtering packages if they don't have com org or net in them would be a very bad move if my project had the same base name for the package.

The intent for this is to become part of an API I'm making so that I can just place the class in my project and use it, without having to edit the parameters that I might use.

Comment: Package.getPackages() returns only a subset of packages, those known to the classloader at the moment the method is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about any method from this... just for classes.
But you could make a own list by letting this run, maybe saving to a file for every operating system in an own program.

```
Package[] pa = Package.getPackages();
for (int i = 0; i < pa.length; i++) {
    Package p = pa[i];
    System.out.print("\"" + p.getName() + "\", ");
}
```

Then load this list and iterate through every package in your other program where you want to filter the packages...

```
String[] systemPackages = new String[]{<all names of the packages>};
Package[] pa = Package.getPackages();
int n = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < pa.length; i++) {
    Package p = pa[i];
    boolean isSystemPackage = false;
    String pname = p.getName();
    for (int j = 0; j < systemPackages.length; j++) {
        String spname = systemPackages[j];
        if (pname.equals(spname)) {
            isSystemPackage = true;
            systemPackages[j] = null;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!isSystemPackage) {
        n++;
    } else {
        pa[i] = null;
    }
}

Package[] projectPackages = new Package[n];
for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < pa.length; i++) {
    Package p = pa[i];
    if (p != null) {
        projectPackages[j] = p;
        j++;
    }
}
```

So you could kind of check it... sure there are different versions of the java-libraries but i dont think you want to use it that serious hm?

Comment: That would work, yes, I do think that that's probably the best option that I can find so far. But it will take a lot of time to fill every package...

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> If there is a way to tell if a package name is a system package, 
> that will do the job perfectly.
> ```

No, there is not 100% sure way to tell which are system packages. Packages java. and javax. are reserved and should be used only as "system" packages, but nothing keeps you from breaking that rule. Also different JDK's have their own packages for implementation, for example com.sun for sun/oracle JDK. Then next problem will be packages defined in other libraries you probably use.

> Is there any way to filter the packages so that only the ones I've
>   defined remain?

It is much easier other way around, just filter in your own packages in (most likely you are using normal package naming strategy and there will be no overlap).

Comment: yeah, I know that, what I was thinking of was somehow a method to check the classname to see if it exists in my project, I tried to scan the jar file but it keeps giving me errors because "Can not access jar file, is it being used by another process" so I don't get how some people cycle through the jar file...